# click event not working in jquery

Tags: jquery

In my following code click event not working can anyone tell me why?
Note: I tried `.live('click', function)` also which is not working so suggest me another solution.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    $(function(){
       $("#signup").click(function(){
       alert("in");
      var street = $("#street").val();
       var mno = $("#mno").val();
      var tno = $("#tno").val();
      var word = $("#word").val();

     //var accept = $("#accept").val(); 
      if(street=="" && mno=="" && tno=="" && word="" &&            document.getElementById('accept').checked==false)
      {
     alert("Enter all the details");

      }

     else if(street=="")
     {
 alert("Enter your street name");

 }
 else if(mno=="")
 {
 alert("Enter your mobile no");

 }
 else if(tno=="")
 {
 alert("Enter your telephone no");

    }
else if(word=="")
{
alert("Enter the word displayed");

}
else if (document.getElementById('accept').checked==false)
{
alert("Accept our terms and conditions");

}
    return false;
    });  
    });  
    </script> 
   <body>
    <div class="inner-content">
             <label for="basic">Street Details:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="street" data-mini="true" />
            <label for="basic">Mobile Number:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="mno" data-mini="true" />
            <label for="basic">Telephone Number:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="tno" data-mini="true" />
            <label for="basic">Enter the word </label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="word" data-mini="true" />
            <label class="check"><input type="checkbox" id="accept"/> I accept the  Terms and Conditions. </label>
             <label class="check"><input type="checkbox" /> Receive mail about   promotions.<br/> Offer and Service. </label>
           <a href="index.html" data-role="button" id="signup">Sign In</a> 
          </div>
        </body>
```

Comment: That code is pretty standard. Could you tell us if you see any js error on your browser?

Comment: Is jQuery included on your page?

Comment: Are you definitely including jquery.js before that on your page?

Comment: Do you definitely have jQuery referenced? If so, what version

Comment: it jus shows error loading page and fades.

Comment: check your firebug console and post here

Comment: Could you please post the full code?

Comment: hm, whoever upvoted this question should explain to me why - "shows ressearch effort, is useful and clear". This can have like 100 reasons for failing. We cannot help you without any error-description.

Comment: @ghommey i posted my full code here

Comment: You don't have to load jquery and jquery.min

Comment: @christoph i posted that it shows error loading page

Comment: @Ghommey i removed n checked the error still occurs

Answer (score 1):

As you can see here, [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cmsZc/) the code is clearly working.

The problem then for you is that the script isn't finding `jQuery` or is it is not finding the `a` tag in your html.

`f12` on Chrome or Firebug for Firefox is what is going to help you out here.

Edit:
You are loading two different `jQuery` scripts, the min version and the non-min version. Try removing `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>`

Also, try: `console.log($('#signup'))` to see if anything was returned.

Comment: i am using android emulator for running the script

Comment: your code works in any browser, therefore, there must be an issue with running it in the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the jQuery file was not properly loaded.. 
Why don't you use the jQuery file hosted by Google cdn .. It will also help reduce file referencing erros and also reduce the bandwidth of your website..

Instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

Use this

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```